# How to calculate multiplicative inverses in $GF(2^3)$ without the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

The problem I have concerns **finite field** arithmetic in $GF(p^k)$.

I know how to find multiplicative inverses using the extended Euclidean algorithm, but for my exams I need to calculate multiplicative inverses in $GF(2^3)$ without it.

What's the best way to do this? Is there even a convenient way?

The irreducible polynomial I have is $x^3 + x + 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{F}_2$ is a pretty small base field, so to find the inverse of an element in $\mathbb{F}_2/(x^3+x+1)=\mathbb{F}_8$ is always really simple. For instance, let us find the inverse of $x^2+x$. For any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{F}_2$

$$ (x^2+x)(ax^2+bx+c) = (c+b-a)x^2+(c-b)x+(a+b) $$
holds in $\mathbb{F}_2/(x^3+x+1)$, so the inverse of $x^2+x$ can be found by solving $c+b-a=0, c-b=0, a+b=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$, leading to $a=0$ and $b=c=1$.
Double-check:
$$ (x+1)(x^2+x) = x^3+x^2+x^2+x = x^3+x = 2x+1 = 1. $$

Comment: Awesome, Thank you! Can you give me a little more explanation about the first Step? So where you got the Solution of the Multiplication of $x^2+x)(ax^2 + bx + c)$ from? I cant see it ..

Comment: @user6431813: by just expanding and exploiting $1+1=0$ and $x^3=x+1$.

Comment: Oh i feel so stupid right now... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, build the table of the so called [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). Let $a$ be a root of $f = x^{3} + x + 1$. Then
\begin{align}
&a^{0} = 1\\
&a^{1} = a\\
&a^{2} = a^{2}\\
&a^{3} = a + 1\\
&a^{4} = a^{2} + a\\
&a^{5} = a^{2} + a + 1\\
&a^{6} = a^{2} + 1\\
&a^{7} = 1\\
\end{align}
So to compute the inverse of $a^{2} + a$, say, you note that $a^{2} + a = a^{4}$. Since $a^{7} = 1$, the inverse of $a^{4}$ is $a^{3} = a + 1$.

Note that in building the table you are doing Euclidean divisions in a simplified form. For instance
$$
a^{5} = a^{4} a = (a^{2} + a) a = a^{3} + a^{2} = a + 1 + a^{2}
$$
since $a$ is a root of $x^{3} + x + 1$, and thus $a^{3} = a + 1$.